Is gibberlic acid present in monocots or not?
As gibberlic acid is a PGR and helps in elongation of stems like in sugarcane,so,if it is present naturally in monocots then rice should also have.
And on other hand foolish seedling disease is caused by a fungus Gibberla fujikoroi with activated substance Gibberlin,then it should not to be said as a PGR for rice seedlings

What do you mean by PGR? Plant growth regulator, plant growth retardant, or something else?

Plant growth regulator

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes, gibberellins (of which gibberellic acid is one member) are present in monocots, which both produce the chemicals and are sensitive to their effects.
In fact, gibberellins are important hormones in all seed plants (and possibly seedless vascular plants). The receptor for gibberellins, GID1, originated with the origin of vascular plants, and one hypothesis is that the canonical gibberellin signalling pathway originated at this time. This study looks at the evolution of the gibberellin signalling pathway.
Gibberella fujikuroi is a fungus that also produces gibberellins (but uses a completely different pathway), and it seems that the fungus takes advantage of the plant's response to gibberellin and the resulting stem lengthening.
